# Vertically fixed ,centered, navigation bar

Tags: navigation, navbar, centering, floating

In the web page I am re-designing, I have a side navigation bar. This bar is fixed and floats as you scroll down the page. It is transparent and follows the screen for easy navigation. It is a nav element with an id="navbar". What I need is to have this navigation bar be centered vertically on all screens. On higher resolution screens it sits high. On lower resolution screens it sits low. How do I center this bar on all screens? Here is a chunk of my code so far. I can provide more if necessary.

This is patial code for one of many pages with the navigation bar:

```
<div id="row">
    <nav id="navbar">
        <ul>
            <li class="button"><a href="page.html">page</a></li>
            <li class="button"><a href="page.php">page</a></li>
            <li class="button"><a style="color: red;"href="page.html">page</a></li>
            <li class="button"><a href="page.html">page</a></li>
            <li class="button"><a href="page.html">page</a></li>
            <li class="button"><a href="page.php">page</a></li>
            <li class="button"><a href="page.html">page</a></li>
            <li class="button"><a href="page.html">page</a></li>
            <li class="button"><a href="page.html">page</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <div id="an id">
        <h1>some text</h1>
        <h3>some text</h3>
        <h5>some text</h5>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my current CSS

```
#row {
    display: table-row;
    margin: 1%;
}

#navbar {
    width: 250px;
    position: fixed;
}

#navbar ul {
    font-size: 110%;
}
```

I'll add this in case any one was wondering about the class="button"

```
li.button {
    background-color: transparent;
    padding: 2px 6px 2px 6px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    border-top: 3px solid #F2F2F2;
    border-right: 2px solid #260000;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #450000;
    border-left: 3px solid #D1D1D1;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the next example "navbarwrapper" keeps "navbar" vertically centered on the left side of the viewport.

```css
#navbarwrapper
{
    display: -webkit-flex ;
    display: flex ;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column ;
    flex-direction: column ;
    -webkit-justify-content: center ;
    justify-content: center ;
    position: fixed ;
    top: 0 ;
    left: 0 ;
    height: 100% ;
    z-index: 999999999 ;
}
#navbar
{
    background-color: #f33 ;
    width: 40px ;
    height: 100px ;
    opacity: 0.8 ;
}
```

```html
<div id="navbarwrapper">
  <div id="navbar"></div>
</div>

<p>sdljdjlj fnfwekjefw efwklefwkwef efwnlewflnnefw</P>
<p>sdljdjlj fnfwekjefw efwklefwkwef efwnlewflnnefw</P>
<p>sdljdjlj fnfwekjefw efwklefwkwef efwnlewflnnefw</P>
<p>sdljdjlj fnfwekjefw efwklefwkwef efwnlewflnnefw</P>
<p>sdljdjlj fnfwekjefw efwklefwkwef efwnlewflnnefw</P>
<p>sdljdjlj fnfwekjefw efwklefwkwef efwnlewflnnefw</P>
<p>sdljdjlj fnfwekjefw efwklefwkwef efwnlewflnnefw</P>
<p>sdljdjlj fnfwekjefw efwklefwkwef efwnlewflnnefw</P>
<p>sdljdjlj fnfwekjefw efwklefwkwef efwnlewflnnefw</P>
<p>sdljdjlj fnfwekjefw efwklefwkwef efwnlewflnnefw</P>
<p>sdljdjlj fnfwekjefw efwklefwkwef efwnlewflnnefw</P>
<p>sdljdjlj fnfwekjefw efwklefwkwef efwnlewflnnefw</P>
<p>sdljdjlj fnfwekjefw efwklefwkwef efwnlewflnnefw</P>
<p>sdljdjlj fnfwekjefw efwklefwkwef efwnlewflnnefw</P>
<p>sdljdjlj fnfwekjefw efwklefwkwef efwnlewflnnefw</P>
<p>sdljdjlj fnfwekjefw efwklefwkwef efwnlewflnnefw</P>
<p>sdljdjlj fnfwekjefw efwklefwkwef efwnlewflnnefw</P>
<p>sdljdjlj fnfwekjefw efwklefwkwef efwnlewflnnefw</P>
<p>sdljdjlj fnfwekjefw efwklefwkwef efwnlewflnnefw</P>
<p>sdljdjlj fnfwekjefw efwklefwkwef efwnlewflnnefw</P>
<p>sdljdjlj fnfwekjefw efwklefwkwef efwnlewflnnefw</P>
<p>sdljdjlj fnfwekjefw efwklefwkwef efwnlewflnnefw</P>
<p>sdljdjlj fnfwekjefw efwklefwkwef efwnlewflnnefw</P>
<p>sdljdjlj fnfwekjefw efwklefwkwef efwnlewflnnefw</P>
<p>sdljdjlj fnfwekjefw efwklefwkwef efwnlewflnnefw</P>
<p>sdljdjlj fnfwekjefw efwklefwkwef efwnlewflnnefw</P>
<p>sdljdjlj fnfwekjefw efwklefwkwef efwnlewflnnefw</P>
<p>sdljdjlj fnfwekjefw efwklefwkwef efwnlewflnnefw</P>
<p>sdljdjlj fnfwekjefw efwklefwkwef efwnlewflnnefw</P>
<p>sdljdjlj fnfwekjefw efwklefwkwef efwnlewflnnefw</P>
<p>sdljdjlj fnfwekjefw efwklefwkwef efwnlewflnnefw</P>
<p>sdljdjlj fnfwekjefw efwklefwkwef efwnlewflnnefw</P>
<p>sdljdjlj fnfwekjefw efwklefwkwef efwnlewflnnefw</P>
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank-you. I did have to remove one line of code from my original CSS as it did not let the navigation bar sit centered. The "fixed" attribute became redundant in the #navbar section.